# logical equivalences with if and only if statements

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I'm trying to show that P→Q ≡ (P∧¬Q)→(Q∧¬Q)

I think I've shown it, but am not 100% sure all my steps are legal.

(P∧¬Q)→(Q∧¬Q)

```
 Step 1) ¬(P∧¬Q) ∨ (Q∧¬Q) (conditional law) 
 Step 2) (¬P∨Q) ∨ (Q∧¬Q) (deMorgan's law) 
 Step 3) ¬P∨Q ∨ Q∧¬Q     (removing parthenses) 
 Step 4) P∨Q∧¬Q          (idempotent law) 
 Step 5) Q ∨ (P∧¬Q)      (commutative law)
 Step 6) (Q∨¬P)∧ (Q∨¬Q)  (distribution law)
 Step 7) (Q∨¬P)          (tautology law) 
 Step 8) P → Q           (conditional law)
```

My question is weather or not step 5 is legal. Can I just invoke the commutative law, and group with parenthesis any way I choose?

Answer (score 1):

The proof is not correct, starting in step 3). You may not have an expression $P\vee Q \wedge R$ since it is not clear what it means without parentheses. That is $P\vee (Q\wedge R)$ is not the same thing as $(P \vee Q)\wedge R$.

Rather in step 3) note that $Q\wedge \neg Q \equiv \bot$ and thus $(\neg P\wedge Q) \vee (Q\wedge \neg Q) \equiv (\neg P\wedge Q)\vee \bot \equiv (\neg P \wedge Q) \equiv P\rightarrow Q$

Answer (score 0):

5 is illegal. The grouping is wrong. $(A\vee B)\wedge C \neq A\wedge(B\vee C)$

It follows the deMorgan's law: $(A\vee B)\wedge C = (A\wedge C)\vee(B\wedge C)$

In addition, step 3 is already wrong.

$(A\vee B)\vee C = A\vee(B\vee C), (A\wedge B)\wedge C = A\wedge(B\wedge C)$    (Associative Law)

$(A\vee B)\wedge C = (A\wedge C)\vee(B\wedge C), (A\wedge B)\vee C = (A\vee C)\wedge(B\vee C)$  (deMorgan's law)